# Bicommutant of self-adjoint subset of an involutive algebra

Tags: c-star-algebras

> 1.1.9. Let $A$ be an involutive algebra and $M$ a self-adjoint subset of $A$... If the elements of $M$ commute pairwise, then $M\subset M'$, so that $M'\supset M''$ and $M''$ is commutative...
>
> <sup>Source: Dixmier's</sup>

Here $M'$ and $M''$ are the commutant and bicommutant of $M$. $M\subset M'$ is pretty straightforward, because each element in $M$ commutes with $M$, so each of the elements in $M$ must belong to the commutant $M'$.  But how to comprehend $M'\supset M''$?  And why would $M''$ be commutative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $A \subset B$, then $B' \subset A'$. Indeed, if $x \in B'$ then $xb = bx$ for every $b \in B$. Since $A \subset B$, we have in particular, that $xa = ax$ for every $a \in A$. Hence $x \in A'$.

Now, $M \subset M'$, hence $M'' \subset M'$ and finally $M'' \subset M'''$. So $M''$ is contained in its commutant, and hence commutative.

Comment: I understand now why $B'\subset A'$, but where along the way was $M=M''$ proved?

Comment: I was too quick. The answer is now corrected.

Comment: Wow, using the tricommutant (?) here is quite neat. Thanks!